# Выдает ошибку NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002

Tags: ios, swift, url

Если отправляю через postman то ответ приходит, в xcode приходит ответ, только если писать английскими буквами название города

```
let string = "http://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=495d8ac5-d573-4880-b69d-d536539908c3&results=10&format=json&geocode=\(city)"
guard let url = URL(string: string) else {return}
```

Comment: Вы создали переменную city?

Comment: Да, я уже разобрался swift не поддерживал русский язык.  Вот код решения                                                                    
                                                  
        var city = "Барнаул"
        var newCity = city.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)